# Limiting an integer to an arrays indeces when incrementing/decrementing

Tags: javascript, math

Consider the following code (`keyCode` is used for backward compatibility):

```
/**
 * Navigate through the items.
 *
 * @param {Event} event
 * @return void
 */
navigate(event) {

    if (event.keyCode === 38 || event.key === "ArrowUp") {
        this.active = this.active + 1 > this.items.length ? 0 : this.active + 1;
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 40 || event.key === "ArrowDown") {
        this.active = this.active - 1 < 0 ? this.items.length : this.active - 1;
    }

}
```

If the above is not clear, what I am trying to do is the following:

- When incrementing `this.active`, make sure it is not greater than the length of `this.items`, and if it is, return it to `0`
- When decrementing `this.active`, make sure it is not less than 0, and if it is, return it to the length of `this.items`

The above code works absolutely fine but I know that it can be done better and more efficiently. For instance, calling `this.active -1` twice in inefficent.

Is there a way to gracefully achieve this using something along the lines of `Math.min` and `Math.Max`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the modulo operator instead:

```
navigate(event) {
    const { length } = items;
    if (event.keyCode === 38 || event.key === "ArrowUp") {
        this.active = (this.active + 1) % length;
    } else if (event.keyCode === 40 || event.key === "ArrowDown") {
        this.active = (this.active - 1 + length) % length;
    }
}
```